# Segmentation fault in new operator

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, reinterpret-cast

**update**: The segmentation fault still exists after correcting the `malloc(sizeof(500))`

I encounter a segmentation fault in following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Data {
  std::string name;

  std::function<int()> work;

  std::vector<int*> v1 {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
  std::vector<int*> v2 {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};

  int* v3 {nullptr};
  int* v4 {nullptr};
};

int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(Data) << "\n";   // Just to make sure sizeof(Data) < 500

  auto raw = malloc(500);      // Allocate memory

  auto int_ptr = static_cast<int*>(raw);
  int_ptr ++; 

  auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(int_ptr);
  new (ptr) Data();                     // GDB reports segmentation fault here

  free(raw);
}
```

The compilation command:

```sh
clang++-9 -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -ggdb3 prog.cpp -lc++abi -O2
```

I think the memory should be large enough to store the `Data`, but why does a segmentation fault happen in `new`?

Comment: Possible alignment problems?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/m36kaz: Error: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Comment: After I correct the typo `sizeof(500)` the compiler explore does not have the assertion error. But the segmentation fault still exists.

Comment: Do you have the backtrace (`bt` in gdb) for the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
auto raw = malloc(sizeof(500));
```

'500' is an integer, so `sizeof(500)` returns 4. I think you meant to do:

```
auto raw = malloc(500);
```

Unrelated, but you might want to do:

```
  auto int_ptr = static_cast<int*>(raw);
  int_ptr += 2;
```

Just so that the pointers remain 8byte aligned *(on the assumption you are using a 64bit OS)*. 
And also, don't forget to call the dtor prior to calling free *(otherwise you have a memory leak)*

```
ptr->~Data();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this!  The `sizeof` is a typo when I copy the code. After I change it to `malloc(500)` I still get the same segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your code has **undefined behavior** due to **incorrect alignment**. I will try to explain it on the following example.

Let's assume that you are on a 64-bit architecture with 4-byte `int`. On such systems, `malloc` typically gives you a 16-byte aligned chunk of memory. Then, when you add 4 bytes to this boundary (`raw` plus 4 bytes), the resulting address (`ptr`) is 4-bytes aligned, but neither 8-bytes nor 16-bytes aligned.

Now, `Data` has some natural alignment, very likely 8-bytes. You can find out it by the `alignof(Data)` expression. When you try to create an object of type `Data` on a 4-bytes aligned address, this [results in undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#1.sentence-1).

---

Also, as pointed out by others, you need to manually call a destructor for the object created by *placement new*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing C++, generally not good form to use malloc. You can use a vector as a buffer, or create an array of chars.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<char> buffer(500);

  auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(buffer.data());
  new (ptr) Data;   
}
```

Comment: note that if you use a vector on the stack as you are suggesting, the buffer get invalidated when exiting the scope. Possibly this is not what someone need to replace a `malloc` call. Also a `ptr->~Data()` is required before exiting the scope, for object created with placement new the dtor is not invoked by compile